# Python - search for pattern within a DataFrame followed by multiple possible strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which one of the columns has a long list of semi-colon separated strings:

> gene_id ENSGACG00000019161; gene_version 1; transcript_id
>   ENSGACT00000025386; transcript_version 1; exon_number 9; gene_name
>   slc7a8a; gene_source ensembl; gene_biotype protein_coding;
>   transcript_name slc7a8a-203; transcript_source ensembl;
>   transcript_biotype protein_coding; exon_id ENSGACE00000225405;
>   exon_version 1;

I want to somehow go row by row and pull out just the string that follows **gene_name** and precedes the semi-colon. So in this case **slc7a8a**. I'm sorry if this is either a simple question or a repetitive one. I've tried to look through multiple resources but don't even know the most concise way to describe what I want to do had difficulty finding anything helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Try this: `df['col_name'].str.extract('gene_name(.*?);')`?

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Worked like a charm. I'm used to working with wildcard characters in a very superficial way so thought it would be along those lines.

Comment: No problem. :) I'm going to post this as an answer just in case someone else needs help with a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) which takes a regex pattern as an input parameter:

```
df['col_name'].str.extract('gene_name(.*?);')
```